# Counting binary numbers

Tags: java, count, binary

I am a beginner in Java Programming and i am having some trouble handling java numbers.
I want to create a program with a loop which will print binary forms of the integers 0 to 5.

i mean the output should be like:
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Try something first. Come back if you have any issues

Comment: You should make an attempt first then ask a question here if you get stuck.

Comment: I have created six different programs but still could not solve this. It was very confusing. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
  System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this was simple. I did not know about the Integer.toBinaryString() method.